# Is it possible to have a body to render angular 4

Tags: angular, grails, angular2-template, transclusion

Is possible to do something like this

mycomponent.html

```
<div>
 <something-content></something-content> <!-- don't know the tag
</div>
```

some other html:

```
<app-mycomponent>
 some random text
<app-mycomponent>
```

results in:

```
 <div>
   some random text
 </div>
```

in grails i would use taglib:

```
Closure mytag = {attr, body ->
  out <<     "<div>"
  out <<       body()
  out <<     "</div>"
}
```

Comment: sounds like ng-content to me

Comment: Jota.Toledo please post it as answer, so I can give you credit. it is correct

Comment: Edited your question and added an answer with some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the feature that you are looking for is content translution. This can be archieved in angular by using ng-content. For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'panel',
  template: `
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-header">
          <ng-content select="panel-header"></ng-content>
        </div>
      </div>
  `
})
export class PanelComponent {}
```

Then you could use:

```
<panel>
  <panel-header>Header title</panel-header>
</panel>
```